# SAT solver SAGE

Tags: python, sage

I'm trying to understand why the solver not found solution in this code

```
R.<x,y,z,w> = BooleanPolynomialRing()
S = PolynomialSequence([x*y+z,x+y])
sol = S.solve(); sol
[]
```

For me the solution is x=1;y=1 and z=1, or I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation for this return value (and how to get a more satisfying one) can be found by carefully reading the documentation for the `solve` method we are using, but I agree with you that this return value is puzzling.

To access the documentation for the method, type `S.solve?`, and to access the source code, type `S.solve??`. This will also reveal the file where this method is defined, and you can then read this file on your system or online on the [Sage source code at GitHub](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/master/src/sage/rings/polynomial/multi_polynomial_sequence.py).

For reference, I work with Sage 6.3. Removing `w` which played no role, and slightly simplifying by writing `Sequence` and not giving the solution a name, your example becomes:

```
sage: R.<x,y,z> = BooleanPolynomialRing()
sage: S = Sequence([x * y + z, x + y])
sage: S.solve()
[]
```

We are indeed surprised, since (0,0,0) and (1,1,1) are two obvious solutions.

```
sage: obvious_0 = {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}
sage: obvious_1 = {x: 1, y: 1, z: 1}
sage: S.subs(obvious_0)
[0, 0]
sage: S.subs(obvious_1)
[0, 0]
```

This is because this `solve` method has an optional parameter `eliminate_linear_variables`, set to `True` by default, which removes all linear occurrences of the variables into the equations. In our example, this just removes all the equations.

And another maybe surprising feature of this `solve` method is that if the polynomial sequence is empty, it returns an empty list:

```
sage: S = S[0:]
sage: S.solve()
```

(whereas one might argue that anything is a solution for an empty list of equations).

To get a solution for the polynomial sequence:

```
sage: S.solve(eliminate_linear_variables=False)
[{z: 0, y: 0, x: 0}]
```

Here we get only one solution. This is because another optional parameter of the `solve` method, `n`, indicates to return at most `n` solutions, with a default set to one. Set it to `Infinity` to get all solutions.

```
sage: S.solve(n=Infinity,eliminate_linear_variables=False)
[{z: 0, y: 0, x: 0}, {z: 1, y: 1, x: 1}]
```